# How to login the sharepoint by passing the username and password?

Tags: python, sharepoint

I am using the `sharepy` and `logging` to connect the sharepoint. I have used the bellow code to connect

```
import sharepy
import logging


SPUrl = "https://vvv.sharepoint.com"

username = "testuserb@vvvv.onmicrosoft.com"
password = "aaa@123"
s = sharepy.connect(SPUrl,username,password)
s.save()

headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
"content-type": "application/x-www-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}
fileToUpload = "copyUpload.py"

with open(fileToUpload, 'rb') as read_file:
    content = read_file.read()
p = s.post("https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/vvv/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/aaa/bbb/')/Files/add(url='"+fileToUpload+"',overwrite=true)", data=content, headers=headers)

print(fileToUpload+" Uploaded in SP")
os.remove(fileToUpload)
logging.info("Uploaded file: with response file")
```

While I am passing the values into the connect function it is throwing the following error

`AttributeError: 'SharePointSession' object has no attribute 'cookie'`

Suppose, If I didn't pass the value as a argument that time in the terminal it will ask for the username and password after typing the it on the terminal it is working fine.

But how can I make it problematically?

I am facing the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "copyUpload.py", line 18, in <module>
    p = s.post("https://aaa.sharepoint.com/sites/Graphite/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/aaa/bbb/')/Files/add(url='"+fileToUpload+"',overwrite=true)", data=content, headers=headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sharepy/session.py", line 135, in post
    kwargs["headers"]["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + self._redigest()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sharepy/session.py", line 111, in _redigest
    data="", headers={"Cookie": self.cookie})
AttributeError: 'SharePointSession' object has no attribute 'cookie'
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace of the error?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Post edited.

Comment: Do you get the `Authentication successful` on the screen?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No while running itself it is throwing error

Comment: Your error is on `post` but looking at `connect` method if auth is successful it should print a message. The above issue will happen when auth is not done or has failed. I can't test without a system but you should just step into the library during debugging and see see what is happening in the auth which happens inside the `connect` method

Comment: Why do you use headers line? Is there any way to handle connection with proxy settings? I am trying just the 'sharepy.connect(SPUrl,username,password)' but connection fails.

Answer (score 2):

The library `sharepy` stores a cookie if the authentication is successful. You can check fore example with

```
if not hasattr(s, 'cookie'):
    print("authentication failed!"); quit()
```

if the authentication has failed, before you save the SharePoint session.

**Common errors**

- wrong username (check that the domain name in your username matches your site)
- wrong password
- wrong site url (**NO** additional characters after *sharepoint.com*, especially no "**/**")

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see what the requirements to authenticate to the page. It seems to me that it is looking for a cookie for authentication. Often applications require a cookie to post data after you authenticated. Try to print out the cookie before you send the POST request to the server. If it prints something out try sending your cookie with your POST request as well by including a cookie parameter.